# Passing string data as categories to Highcharts

Tags: javascript, string, graph, highcharts

I have a problem with passing data to Highcharts chart.

I am ok with passing the "data" variables, because they are numbers. What doesnt seem to work are the categories. Here I have text values for the individual data points. I created a string which looks something like this:

```
string = "'One','Two','Three','Four'";
```

I then passed this as the categories in Highcharts like this:

```
xAxis: {

   categories: string,

},
```

The problem is that when I do this, instead of x-values being One, Two etc. I get each letter of the string as a category - ie. the first categorz is the apostrophe, second O, third n....

I know there is a problem that I need to somehow create an array and pass it in the correct format, but I tried various things and nothing worked.

Just to add, if one is not using dynamic data, the syntax for highcharts should look like this for example:

```
xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Jan',
            'Feb',
            'Mar',
            'Apr',
            'May',
            'Jun',
            'Jul',
            'Aug',
            'Sep',
            'Oct',
            'Nov',
            'Dec'
        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `split(',')` method:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: string.split(',')
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
xAxis: {

   categories: string.replace(/'/g, "").split(",")

},
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

$string = "'One','Two','Three','Four'";

```
 xAxis: {
                categories:   [<?php echo $string; ?>]
                ,
                crosshair: true
            },
```